# C# Xamarin.Forms, Create a background service to loop HTTP Request and push notification

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, service, background

I'm having a problem to create a Background Service to loop a http request, and push notification if data is changed.
In android:
First time, i try to use Service, it's run very nice but it don't run when i close the app.
Second time, i try to use JobService, but it's do nothing. When debug, i see i maybe i can't reach to the JobService.
Code of Job Service:

```
public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters @params)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                CheckData();// my code here
            }
            ); 
            return true;
        }

public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters @params)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

In Main Activity:

```
Java.Lang.Class javaClass = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(NotificationJobService));
            ComponentName component = new ComponentName(ApplicationContext, javaClass);


            JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, component)
                .SetRequiresCharging(true)
                .SetRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.Unmetered)
                .SetPersisted(true)
                .SetPeriodic(3000);

            JobInfo jobInfo = builder.Build();
            JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)GetSystemService(JobSchedulerService);
            int res = jobScheduler.Schedule(jobInfo);
```

Comment: Try this plugin: https://github.com/winstongubantes/MatchaBackgroundService

Comment: i tried it, but don't work for me :(

Comment: when i close app, the service not run

Comment: Read the Quirks and Limitation:https://github.com/winstongubantes/MatchaBackgroundService#quirks-and-limitation
Starting with Android Oreo it has already introduced the background execution limits similar to iOS background time limits assuming the app is in background mode or app is closed or minimized, as discuss on this article.